# Could not create directory /home/username/.mysql/workbench/log: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, workbench

I get this error when I open up MySQL workbench on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. And I can't even connect to database. I just installed mysql workbech using '''sudo apt install mysql-workbench'''.

I'm new to Ubuntu and MySQL. Can someone help me with this? Any further information regarding this will be provided.

Comment: What do you see when you execute the ff. bash command `ll /home/username/.mysql/workbench/log`, your error suggests that it doesn't have enough permission to write logs in that particular folder

Comment: i would suggest researching how permissions work on linux/unix related systems -> [Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/)

Comment: Execute this command `ls -l /home/username/.mysql/workbench/log`, and edit your question to include the output of the same.